# Outlook add-in getAccessToken error 13003

Tags: office365, single-sign-on, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have developed an Office add-in. I have trouble with one of my customers. On some Outlook desktop clients, when the function:
OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({allowConsentPrompt: true, allowSignInPrompt: true})

I get the error 13003 (User Type not supported). I confirm that my customer is logged in with his Microsoft 365 account and that he is not on-premises. He is on a recent version of Outlook (16.0.13426.20352).

I am not sure what to do as it works well on the 2 Microsoft organizations I own for tests purposes.

Do you have any idea of what could be not configured correctly?

Comment: Modern Auth may need to be turned on for that Exchange Server: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/enable-or-disable-modern-authentication-in-exchange-online

Comment: It works! Thank you! You should add the cause of the error on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins

Comment: We will update our documentation to make this clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern auth needed to be turned on (kudos to @Outlook Add-in Team).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/enable-or-disable-modern-authentication-in-exchange-online

Mordern auth is **Off** by default for tenants created before **August 1, 2017**.